# Expansion of \ifnum creates a weird \relax token

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, expansion

There was I, procrastinating over some TeX code while I should have been writing my dissertation. The code was working more or less fine (better than the writing, at least), until a mysterious `\relax` popped up from nowhere!

At first I though it was something stupid from my end, but when I reduced the code to a bare minimum I realised I had no idea what was going on. I reduced the code to use basically only primitives, so it shouldn't be any coding problem. Here's the guilty code:

```latex
\def\useIInnn#1#2#3{#2}
\def\useIInn#1#2{#2}
\detokenize\expandafter{\ifnum0=0\expandafter\useIInnn\fi\useIInn{1}{\BOOM}}
\bye
```

and its output is (surprisingly, for me):

```
\relax \fi {1}{\BOOM }
```

Where did that `\relax` come from?

---

I realise that the test wouldn't result in `0=0` because `\ifnum` would continue expanding tokens (as far as I understand, it would make `0=01` and result false; I corrected this in the code :). However the `\relax` remains a mystery for me.

Comment: Crosslink: Special case of [macros - Accessing TeX's internal tokens - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609423/accessing-texs-internal-tokens) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see what happens. The tokens `\ifnum0=0` are not a full test, because by rule TeX expands tokens until finding an unexpandable token that cannot be interpreted as a digit; if this token is a space, it will be swallowed. However, TeX will *never* go past the matching `\else` or `\fi` when expanding tokens in the process of determining a conditional test.

The token following `0` is `\expandafter`, which expands the `\fi`: oh, this means that the conditional has to be evaluated! In such cases, that is, whenever a conditional text is unfinished at the time `\else` or `\fi` appear and have to be expanded, TeX inserts a special `\relax` token, called *frozen `\relax`*.

You get a frozen `\relax` also in cases such as `\if x\fi`; two in the case of `\if\fi`.

This is module 379 in `tex.web`.

Comment: Hm, cool, it's a type of safety. It's easy to see the `\relax`es appearing with `\unravel{\expandafter{\if\fi}}` (I actually saw it earlier, but it didn't make sense). Thanks :-)