# Purpose of \expandafter in a particular macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

Consider the following set of definitions...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\def\foreach{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=12 \xforeach}

{\catcode`\^^M=12
  \gdef\xforeach #1^^M{%
    \first #1,,\endgroup}}

\def\first #1,{%
  \if,#1,
  \else Do something with `#1'.\par\expandafter\first
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\foreach a,cde
\end{document}
```

I would be happy if you could explain to me the meaning (or function) of `\expandafter` in the macro `\first` defined above.

My guess is that the `\expandafter` closes the `\if`-test and, consequently, `\first` is inserted. I wouldn't be surprised if I'm wrong.

I will appreciate a detailed description of experienced TeX users.

Comment: Your guess is correct. The `\expandafter` skips over `\first` and expands `\fi`, thus removing it so that the conditional is propeproperly ended before `\first` is used a second time (I love the contradiction :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Could you rewrite your comment as a regular answer to accept it?

Comment: The reason is that \first needs to grab the argument AFTER #1, but the \fi is in the way.

Comment: See also https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_does_%5Cexpandafter_work:_A_detailed_macro_case_study for a case study, which involves a more elaborate `...\expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}\fi...` construction.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using the endline as a delimiter for the argument to `\foreach` and not simply using braces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your guess is correct. `\expandafter` always skips over one token (in this case, `\first`) and expands the next one (in this case, `\fi`). The expansion of `\fi` (or `\else`, which are somewhat similar) ends the current conditional and removes the `\fi` token.

Suppose the `\expandafter` wasn't there: the first iteration of `\first` (which could use a better name, in my opinion) would be:

```
\if,a,
\else Do something with `a'.\par\first
\fi cde,,\endgroup
```

The `\if` test would be false, so The `\else` branch would be taken. `` Do something with `a'.\par `` would be typeset and then `\first` would expand once more. This time, `\first` would grab (everything to the next `,`) `\fi cde` as argument, and the next iteration would be:

```
%   V----V frozen \relax
\if,\relax\fi cde,
\else Do something with `\fi cde'.\par\first
\fi cde,,\endgroup
```

Now the `\if` test would see the `\fi` token before the conditional was complete, so TeX would insert a [frozen `\relax`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490324/134574) and the test `\if,\relax` would yield false, so TeX would skip to the next `\fi`, which is the one right after the `\relax`. Now `cde,` would be (wrongly) typeset and then TeX, still in the `\else` branch of the first iteration of `\first`, would see another `\else` and would complain:

```
! Extra \else.
\first #1,->\if ,#1, \else
                           Do something with `#1'.\par \first \fi
l.19 \foreach a,cde
```

---

That said, I'd change your code a bit:

1. I'd issue the `\endgroup` before the loop starts, so that you wouldn't need to worry, for example, with the common issue of definitions inside a PGF `\foreach`;
2. I'd move all the `` Do something with `#1' `` *outside* the conditional, so that possible conditional tokens (`\if`, `\else`, `\fi`, etc.) in the argument won't interfere with the conditional of the loop; and
3. I'd use a safer emptiness test (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513337/134574) for some examples); `\if,#1,` is dangerous in case of conditional tokens in the argument (as you saw above) and in case the item you're looping contains a comma as in, for example `\foreach a,{,b},c`. Better yet, I'd use a unique token to test the end of the loop, so that empty items are allowed (they are not in your current code).

That said, here's the changed code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\foreach{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=12 \xforeach}
{\catcode`\^^M=12
  \gdef\xforeach #1^^M{%
  \endgroup%
    \first #1,,}}
\def\first #1,{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\@gobble}%
    {Do something with `#1'.\par}%
  \first}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foreach a,cde
\end{document}
```

You could also extend it to put the `do something` code inline:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\foreach{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=12 \xforeach}
{\catcode`\^^M=12
  \long\gdef\xforeach #1^^M#2{%
  \endgroup%
  \def\marian@temp##1{#2}%
    \first #1,,}}
\def\first #1,{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\@gobble}%
    {\marian@temp{#1}}%
  \first}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foreach a,cde
  {Do something with `#1'.\par}
\end{document}
```

Or with `expl3`'s `\clist_map_inline:nn`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \foreach
  {
    \group_begin:
      \char_set_catcode_other:N \^^M
      \__marian_foreach:wn
  }
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_other:N \^^M
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__marian_foreach:wn #1 ^^M #2
  {
    \group_end:
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {#2}
  }
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\foreach a,cde
  {Do something with `#1'.\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed instructions. In fact, I'm interested only in plain TeX solutions. Regardless of this, `expl3` notation contains a lot of spaces and underscores which is hard to read (at least for me and at this moment).

Comment: @MarianG. You're welcome! I wrote the code in LaTeX because your code was too, but all of them (including the `expl3` one, given you load it with `\input expl3-generic`) should work in Plain (you might need to define `\def\@gobble#1{}`, `\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}` and `\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}`). If you want to use Knuth TeX (that is, no e-TeX), then you need a different emptiness test (which doesn't rely on `\detokenize`); I recommend the **Fast `\ifempty`** test in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517265/134574).

Comment: @MarianG. Also, `expl3` isn't that hard, once you get used to its verbosity :-) In case you're interested, the `expl3` code is more or less a one-to-one adaptation of the one above: `\cs_new_protected:Npn` replaces `\def` (the definition is `\protected` because it's not safely expandable), `\group_begin:` replaces `\begingroup`, `\char_set_catcode_other:N` does as it advertises, and `\__marian_foreach:wn` replaces `\xforeach` with a proper namespace. In `\__marian_foreach:wn`, `\group_end:` replaces `\endgroup` and `\clist_map_inline:nn` does the looping over the comma-separated list.